# Find normal vector of a 3d vector

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, 3d

I need to find the normal vector for the following 3d vector presented in the vectorial equation because I need to find a plane that is orthogonal to the following line:

> $(x,y,z)=(1,0,0)+k(1,2,3)$

I understand that two normal vectors will have a dot product of $0$, however, I am not sure what to do in 3D space?

In 2D space, if I have an equation of **$(x,y) = (p1,p2) +k(a,b)$**, I know that the normal vector would be $(-b,a)$.

Furthermore, I would like to ask if I have an equation for plan: $2x+3y+4z=0$, in which $(2,3,4)$ is the normal vector. How can I obtain the direction vector for this plan?

Thanks!

Comment: There will be an entire plane perpendicular to any given vector. If you want just one vector   try something like $(-2,1,0)$

Comment: @pooja okay. But how can I find that? I mean is there any method? Like the formula that I know for 2D space is (-b,a).

Comment: Not that hard to see $(a,b,c)$ and $(-b,a,0)$ are perpendicular to each other. Take dot product.

Comment: Why do you need to find a vector that’s normal to the line to solve the original problem? What you need is a normal vector to the _plane_ that you’ve been tasked with finding, and you already have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $3$ dimensions, there are infinitely many vectors perpendicular to a given vector.

As you said $(x,y,z)\perp(1,2,3)\iff x+2y+3z=0$.

One solution is $(x,y,z)=(1,1,-1)$ by inspection.

One way to find a vector perpendicular to a given vector in $3$ dimensions is to take the cross-product with another (non-collinear) vector.

For example, $(1,0,0)\times(1,2,3)=(0,-3,2)$ is perpendicular to both $(1,0,0)$ and $(1,2,3)$, as you can verify by showing their dot product is $0$.

Now that we have two vectors perpendicular to $(1,2,3)$, any linear combination of those two vectors $\alpha(1,1,-1)+\beta(0,-3,2)$ with $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$ will also be perpendicular to $(1,2,3)$.

Comment: Okay. Now I understand. However, according to the answer key that my professor did, it says "the normal vector of the plan is the same as the direction vector as the line (So the normal vector of the plan is (1,2,3) as well)". I feel this is wrong, but I am not certain

Comment: The equation for the plane perpendicular to $(1,2,3)$ is indeed $x+2y+3z=c$.

Comment: So they are always the same? A plan orthogonal to $(x,y,z) = (1,0,0)+k(3,2,1)$ would have an equation of $3x+2y+z = 0$ ?

Comment: The plane would have an equation of $3x+2y+z=c$ for some real number $c$.  For every real number $c$, there is a plane orthogonal to $(3,2,1)$.  These planes are all parallel.  For the plane containing the origin, $3x+2y+z=0$.

Comment: Okay! Thanks! I am now clearer! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @YanZhuang you may like seeing it in 3d https://www.geogebra.org/3d/tr52ed5g

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will try to enter them in!

Answer (score 1):

The condition you need is that the dot product is $0$, as you said. Therefore, for any point $(x,y,z)$, you have
$$
(x,y,z)\cdot (1,2,3)=0\Leftrightarrow x+2y+3z=0.
$$
Naturally, there are infinitely many solutions to this equation (the solution describes a plane). One, for example, is the vector $(2,-1,0)$.

Comment: Sure thanks! I understand now!